# how can get database name in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get WordPress database name. I have also try to get database name from `$wpdb` but failed. When print the $wpdb it give an object array but i don't know how to get database name from object array.

Answer (score 9):

**you can get anywhere your db name using**

```
 <?php  echo DB_NAME; ?>

 <?php echo DB_USER; ?>
```

or

**To get the db name using $wpdb:**

```
global $wpdb;
echo $wpdb->dbname;
```

**It will return database name as a string.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get database name by DB_NAME constant.You can check by printing it

```
<?php echo DB_NAME; ?>
```